# Angular2 SharedModule issue

Tags: angular, ng2-bootstrap

I'm moving all shared modules into a named `SharedModule` module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
import { StoreDevtoolsModule } from '@ngrx/store-devtools';

import { AlertModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap';
import { Select2Module } from 'ng2-select2';

export const modules = [
  CommonModule,
  ReactiveFormsModule,
  FormsModule,
  HttpModule,
  RouterModule,
  StoreModule,
  StoreDevtoolsModule,
  AlertModule,
  Select2Module
];

export const declarations = [];

@NgModule({
  imports: modules,
  exports: [...modules, ...declarations],
  declarations
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

As you can see, I'm using `AlertModule`. Nevertheless I'm getting an issue in my `LoginComponent` when it's loaded:

```
caused by: No provider for AlertConfig!
```

`LoginModule` is:

```
export const routes = [
  { path: '', component: LoginComponent, pathMatch: 'full' }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    LoginComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    SharedModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
  ]
})
export default class LoginModule {
  static routes = routes;
}
```

and it's loaded lazily using `Router`. The routes are:

```
export const ROUTES: Routes = [{
   path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full'
}, {
    path: 'app',   loadChildren: () => System.import('./layout/layout.module')
  }, {
    path: 'login', loadChildren: () => System.import('./login/login.module')
  }, {
    path: 'signin', loadChildren: () => System.import('./signin/signin.module')
  }, {
    path: 'validate', loadChildren: () => System.import('./validate/validate.module')
  }, {
    path: 'error', component: ErrorComponent
  }, {
    path: '**',    component: ErrorComponent
  }
];
```

related html code in `login.template.html`:

```
<div class="clearfix">
    <alert *ngFor="let alert of alerts; let i = index" [type]="alert.type + ' alert-sm'" (close)="closeAlert(i)" dismissible="true">
        <div [innerHTML]="alert.msg"></div>
    </alert>
</div>
```

If I import `AlertModule` using `AlertModule.forRoot()` in my `app.module.ts` I'm getting this template parse error:

Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'type' since it isn't a known property of 'alert'. ("

```
<alert *ngFor="let alert of alerts; let i = index" [ERROR ->][type]="alert.type + ' alert-sm'" (close)="closeAlert(i)" dismissible="true">

                  <div"): LoginComponent@35:67
'alert' is not a known element:
1. If 'alert' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'alert' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
              </div>

              <div class="clearfix">

                [ERROR ->]<alert *ngFor="let alert of alerts; let i = index" [type]="alert.type + ' alert-sm'" (close)="closeAl"): LoginComponent@35:16
BaseError@http://localhost:3002/vendor.bundle.js:15859:9 [angular]
SyntaxError@http://localhost:3002/vendor.bundle.js:35689:9 [angular]
ac_vendor<["./node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/template_parser/template_parser.js"]/TemplateParser.prototype.parse@http://localhost:3002/vendor.bundle.js:34130:19 [angular]
```

Comment: Where an d how do you provide `AlertConfig`?

Comment: https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap/issues/1365 it requires `forRoot`   `AlertModule.forRoot()`

Comment: Thanks @GünterZöchbauer I'm using directly html code, nothing else.

Comment: https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap/issues/1402

Comment: @suraj. I'm using usual way your issue comments... What's worng in my code according this issue?

Comment: try importing it again in your root module with `forRoot()`. I was trying to show the last comment in the second link I posted

Comment: Please post the `AlertModule.forRoot()` function

Comment: `AlertModule.forRoot = function () {
        return { ngModule: AlertModule, providers: [AlertConfig] };
    };`

Comment: If alert config is a service you will need to provide it in one of the modules that you are importing or in the shared module. `providers: [AlertConfig]`